# Cloning records from 1 object to another object

Tags: exception, list, clone

I have 2 different objects objA and objB with same object model(all the fields api name and no of fields are same). Now when a change happens I want to clone the same records from objA to objB. It is possible by mapping the fields of both objects. Is it possible by simply moving the list to another list(this will cause run time TypeException). So is their any other way to perform this process, plz guide me the best way. Or is their any way to define to which object to be inserted while `Database.Insert(cloneFromMe, true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the field names are exactly the same, then you can use the below code to copy across from ObjA to ObjB

```
ObjA__c yourObjASource;
ObjB__c yourObjBTarget;

Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> fieldNames = Schema.SObjectType.ObjA__c.fields.getMap();

for(String fieldName : fieldNames){
    yourObjBTarget.put(fieldName,yourObjASource.get(fieldName));        
}
```

you have to take care of how you identify the corresponding record of Object B when a particular record of Object A changes..

once you know that you can use the above code snippet to copy across the field values..